# How to load fonts, CSS, JS and Images in chrome extension manifest v3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

I am building a chrome extension which works on the Gmail site. As of now, there is no CSP in my manifest.json

I am in the middle of migrating it to manifest v3 from v2. I found out that [remote loading](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code) is now not allowed in v3. So does that mean one cannot load fonts, CSS, and js from links like -`@import url("https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/google-sans");`

When I did this, I think the font was getting loaded but the console showed an error -

```
"Access to font at 'https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/14955/ProductSans-Regular.woff' from origin 'https://mail.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."


"GET https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/14955/ProductSans-Regular.woff net::ERR_FAILED 503"
```

When I see the "Elements" tab in the dev tools, I can see -

```
font-family: "Google Sans",Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
```

So, is the font getting loaded? If I deselect this CSS style from the elements tab, the font changes in my extension.

Apart from this, I am also loading images in my file -

`<img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/table-properties.png"/>`
These are loading perfectly. Why? Shouldn't this be blocked?

- What is happening here?
- What is the correct way of loading fonts, CSS and JS files in my chrome extensions?
- If manifest v3 doesn't allow remote loading, what is the point of writing a custom CSP?

Answer (score 1):

1. When you look at CSS you only see the text rule, not the actual resource being used. Look at the bottom of the "Computed" panel where it shows the actually used font.
2. Gmail already loads google-sans font, which is why the font changes when you deselect this CSS rule.
3. img.icons8.com are loading perfectly because the server sets `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` whereas fonts.cdnfonts.com doesn't as the error message says.

You can include the resources in your extension directory, expose them via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/), and add into the page.

> what is the point of writing a custom CSP

Well, to make it even stricter. Yeah, funny, I know. ManifestV3 is inherently nonsensical because it's devised by impractical idealists, and it still has a lot of critical bugs, but hopefully it'll change in the future as we report the real use cases we encounter on https://crbug.com.